# How to request for two different URL from Arduino one after another?

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm

In the following code segment I am obtaining latitude, longitude, time, date and speed using GPS SKG13BL with Arduino UNO and then send it to the database via  GSM module at every 5 secs. And if the speed (stored to `s`) returned by GPS is greater than 0, then an LED glows else will be low. After this code segment I am performing the database insertion by calling a URL. This works fine and obtains the results as I thought.

Code:

```cpp
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>

//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
#include <NMEAGPS.h>

NeoSWSerial GSM(2, 3); // RX, TX: Connect TXD to RX & RXD to TX

static const int RXPin = 8, TXPin = 9;  //when looking from antenna of gps , Last TTL pin is to be connected to 8 and second one to 9
AltSoftSerial gpsPort(RXPin, TXPin);
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

NMEAGPS gps;
gps_fix fix;
uint8_t fixCount = 0;
char dt[15],tm[15],lati[10],longi[10],rno[13]="kl-05-jb-007";
//int block = 0;

enum _parseState {
  PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE,

  PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO,

  PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE,

  PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE,
  PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT,
  PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH,

  PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH,
  PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT
};

enum _actionState {
  AS_IDLE,
  AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE
};

byte actionState = AS_IDLE;
unsigned long lastActionTime = 0;

int s;

byte parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
char buffer[160],url[160];
byte pos = 0;

int contentLength = 0;

void resetBuffer() {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  pos = 0;
}

void sendGSM(const char* msg, int waitMs = 500) {
  GSM.println(msg);
  while(GSM.available()) {
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
  //delay(waitMs);
}

void setup()
{
  GSM.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsPort.begin(GPSBaud);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //pin 13 to be connected to positive of LED via a resistor
  Serial.println(F("Hinder LOADING....."));
  Serial.println(F("obtain gps and store data to database"));
  Serial.println(F("Testing by : "));
  Serial.println(F("Nikhil,Muthumani and Mathews"));
  Serial.println();

  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"vodafone\"");  
  delay(500);
  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=1,1",3000);
  delay(500);
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPINIT"); 
  delay(500); 
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  delay(500);
}

void loop()
{ 
  unsigned long now = millis();
  while (gps.available( gpsPort )) {
    fix = gps.read();
     //Serial.println(F("b"));
    // Once every 5 seconds...    
    if (++fixCount >= 5) {
       //Serial.println(F("a"));
      displayInfo();
      if(s>0) // Change led state when speed greater than 0 or less than 0
         digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      else
         digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      //send the next report if previous one is finished
      if ( actionState == AS_IDLE ) {
      sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://hinder.000webhostapp.com/HInsert.php?rno=%s&lat=%s&lng=%s&speed=%d&date=%s&time=%s\"",rno,lati,longi,s,dt,tm );
      sendGSM(url);
     // lastActionTime = now;
      parseState = PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE; // a new state
      actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
      fixCount = 0;
    }

    }
  }

/*  if ((gps.statistics.chars < 10) && (millis() > 5000)) {
     Serial.println( F("No GPS detected: check wiring.") );
     while(true);
     block=1;
    }*/

  while(GSM.available()) {
    //lastActionTime = now;
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
 }


void displayInfo()
{
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.location) {
    dtostrf( fix.latitude(),7,5,lati);
    //sprintf(lati,"%d",fix.latitude(),5);
    Serial.print(lati);
    Serial.print( ',' );
    dtostrf( fix.longitude(),8,5,longi);
    //sprintf(longi,"%d",fix.longitude(),5);
    Serial.print(longi);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Speed: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.speed) {
    s=fix.speed_kph();
    Serial.print(s);
    Serial.print(F(" KMPH "));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  // Shift the date/time to local time
  NeoGPS::clock_t localSeconds;
  NeoGPS::time_t  localTime;
  if (fix.valid.date && fix.valid.time) {
    using namespace NeoGPS; // save a little typing below...

    localSeconds = (clock_t) fix.dateTime; // convert structure to a second count
    localSeconds += 5 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR + 30 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE; // shift timezone
    localTime = localSeconds;              // convert back to a structure
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date : "));
  if (fix.valid.date) {
    sprintf(dt,"%02d/%02d/20%d",fix.dateTime.date,fix.dateTime.month,fix.dateTime.year);
    Serial.print(dt);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Time : "));
  if (fix.valid.time) {
    if (localTime.hours>12)localTime.hours-=12;//To convert 24 hr format to 12 hr format
    sprintf(tm,"%02d:%02d:%02d",localTime.hours,localTime.minutes,localTime.seconds);
    Serial.print(tm);
    //block=1;
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.println();
}

void parseATText(byte b) {

  buffer[pos++] = b;

  if ( pos >= sizeof(buffer) )
    resetBuffer(); // just to be safe

  /*
   // Detailed debugging
   Serial.println();
   Serial.print("state = ");
   Serial.println(state);
   Serial.print("b = ");
   Serial.println(b);
   Serial.print("pos = ");
   Serial.println(pos);
   Serial.print("buffer = ");
   Serial.println(buffer);*/

  switch (parseState) {

  case PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE:
    {
      parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
      sendGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
     /*  while(GSM.available()) {
    //lastActionTime = now;
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }*/

    }
    break;

  case PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE: 
    {
      if ( b == '\n' )
        resetBuffer();
      else {        
        if ( pos == 3 && strcmp(buffer, "AT+") == 0 ) {
          parseState = PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO;
        }
        else if ( b == ':' ) {
          //Serial.print("Checking message type: ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);

          if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPACTION:") == 0 ) {
            Serial.println("Received HTTPACTION");
            parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE;
          }
          else if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPREAD:") == 0 ) {
            Serial.println("Received HTTPREAD");            
            parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH;
          }
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        Serial.print("Ignoring echo: ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE:
    {
      if ( b == ',' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION type is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT:
    {
      if ( b == ',' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION result is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION length is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);

        // now request content
        GSM.print("AT+HTTPREAD=0,");
        GSM.println(buffer);

        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        contentLength = atoi(buffer);
        Serial.print("HTTPREAD length is ");
        Serial.println(contentLength);

        Serial.print("HTTPREAD content: ");

        parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT:
    {
      // for this demo I'm just showing the content bytes in the serial monitor
      Serial.write(b);

      contentLength--;

      if ( contentLength <= 0 ) {

        // all content bytes have now been read

        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();

        Serial.print("\n\n\n");

        actionState = AS_IDLE;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Now I need a modification in this as, when the speed is greater than 0, along with the glowing of the LED, a variable `flag` (`int flag=0;` declared globally) is incremented. And `flag` is set to 0 when the speed is equal to 0. And if the flag value becomes 2 (i.e when speed is greater than 0 for two consecutive readings) I want to send latitude, longitude, date, time and speed at that instant to another database which is also done by calling a URL (`url1`). And after that I want to send that to the usual database by calling its URL (`url`).

I did a modification as follows :

```cpp
if(s>0) // Change led state when speed greater than 0 or less than 0
   {       
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      flag++;
      }          
  else
       {
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
         flag=0;
          }
 if(flag==2)
    {
      sprintf(url1, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://speed.000webhostapp.com/HInsert.php?rno=%s&lat=%s&lng=%s&speed=%d&date=%s&time=%s\"",rno,lati,longi,s,dt,tm );
      sendGSM(url1);
      parseState = PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE; // a new state
      actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
     }
```

This doesn't obtain result as I thought. Can anyone help me. Is it possible to have `flag` variable working this way in `loop()`. Is there a problem with my usage of `flag` or is it another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bit tough to make arduino request for two URLs as we would have to handle two separate request and its responses, either the two request would merge in and wont obtain required result or the code would become large that arduino-uno wont be able to handle.

So i found an easy way for doing that, i.e to request for the second PHP page from the first PHP page (which is requested by arduino itself). The only difference between these two request was that the second one need an extra variable. I passed along with the first request so it was available for making request from first page.

I changed arduino code as follows :

1. First I modified the portion making the check - just after the `displayinfo();`, as I mentioned in the question, added a flag bit to it. So it become like this :

   ```
   if(s>0) // s is speed
     {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //if speed exceeds limit then LED is set to HIGH
      flag++;
     }
   else
    {
     digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
     flag=0;
    }
   ```
2. The URL for request from arduino was added with the `flag` variable too. (For the request for second page).

   ```
   sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://hinder.000webhostapp.com/HInsert.php?flag=%d&rno=%s&lat=%s&lng=%s&speed=%d&date=%s&time=%s\"",flag,rno,lati,longi,s,dt,tm );
   ```

In the PHP code I added following lines :

```
if ( $flag == 2 )
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://masp203.000webhostapp.com/RTO.php?rno=".$rno."&date=".$date."&time=".$time."&speed=".$speed."&street=".$street."" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
}
```

This worked just the way I wanted it to be.

Hope this helps some one.